# How to insert 1 million records into table database Oracle using cross join

Tags: mysql, database, oracle, cross-join

i want to insert one million record in oracle DB table. i have achieved similar task in mysql using cross join as follows :

1) insert 10 records first.

```
insert into spltest_sampleapl2 values (10001, 'aaaa');
insert into spltest_sampleapl2 values (10002, 'bbbbb');
insert into spltest_sampleapl2 values (10003, 'ccccc');
insert into spltest_sampleapl2 values (10004, 'dddddd');
insert into spltest_sampleapl2 values (10005, 'eeeeeeeee');
insert into spltest_sampleapl2 values (10006, 'ffffff');
insert into spltest_sampleapl2 values (10007, 'gggggggg');
insert into spltest_sampleapl2 values (10008, 'hhhhhh');
insert into spltest_sampleapl2 values (10009, 'iiiiii');
insert into spltest_sampleapl2 values (10010, 'jjjjjj');
commit;
```

2) using user-variable

```
set @num := 10010;
```

3) insert records with single-join

```
insert into apl2 (id, data) select (@num := @num + 1) ,s1.data from apl2 s1, apl2 s2, apl2 s3, apl2 s4,apl2 s5, apl2 s6;
commit;
```

Now i want to do the same on similar schema in Oracle. How to do it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First i inserted record having id from 1000000 to 1000010 (10 records), then i used following command.

```
insert into apl2(id, data) select rownum ,s1.data from apl2 s1, apl2 s2, apl2 s3, apl2 s4, apl2 s5, apl2 s6 where rownum < 1000001;
```

Answer (score 2):

Create a table with 10 records, numbered 0 to 10:

```
INSERT INTO t (n) VALUES (0);
INSERT INTO t (n) VALUES (1);
...
INSERT INTO t (n) VALUES (9);
```

Now `select` a cross-join, utilizing as many aliases as you want 10^n count:

For 100 records:

```
INSERT INTO X 
SELECT t2.n*10 + t1.n FROM t t1, t t2
```

For 1000 records:

```
INSERT INTO X 
SELECT t3.n*100 + t2.n*10 + t1.n FROM t t1, t t2, t t3
```

For 1,000,000 records:

```
INSERT INTO X 
SELECT t6.n*100000 + t5.n * 10000 + t4.n*1000 + t3.n*100 + t2.n*10 + t1.n FROM t t1, t t2, t t3
```

I'm pretty sure this is vanilla SQL that would work on any platform...

Answer (score 0):

Set up a sequence and use that for the auto-numbering:

```
create sequence seq_apl2;

insert into apl2(id, data)
    select seq_apl2.nextval, s1.data
    from apl2 s1 cross join apl2 s2 cross join
         apl2 s3 cross join apl2 s4 cross join
         apl2 s5 cross join apl2 s6;
```

EDIT:

If you don't have the ability to use sequences, then use `row_number()`:

```
insert into apl2(id, data)
    select row_number() over (order by NULL), s1.data
    from apl2 s1 cross join apl2 s2 cross join
         apl2 s3 cross join apl2 s4 cross join
         apl2 s5 cross join apl2 s6;
```

You can add an offset if you like.

Comment: this way how can i be sure of the primary key range ?

Comment: @SubhamTripathi . . . You can start the sequence at whatever value you like or alter it to start on another value (http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28310/views002.htm#ADMIN11795).

Comment: my user do not have permission to create sequence, is there any other solution.

Comment: You can use Oracle 12, which supports auto-incrementing ids in the create table statement.

Comment: when i use above (edited solution) it gives some kind of error.  but when i use this :: `insert into apl2(id, data) select rownum ,s1.data from apl2 s1, apl2 s2, apl2 s3, apl2 s4, apl2 s5, apl2 s6 where rownum < 1000001;`  it runs properly

Comment: Oh, yes.  `rownum` is a simpler way to get what you want.